# Jquery mouseover/out issue

Tags: jquery

Alright I made this nav, that has a sub nav on certain locations. Currently the trigger is the main menu item. Now this works perfectly for all purposes of showing the menus however. When I mouseout off the main menu item the submenu item closes out. I tried putting it on a interval to give it a second to catch an instance of someone possibly going over the submenu item but that in itself causes problems specially if the person goes over another menu in the mean time. I've bricked myself in and can't think of a way to handle this better.. so here is the existing code:

```
var menuTimeout = '';
$('.nav_click').bind({
mouseover: function(){
if($(this).hasClass('submenus') == true){
var whichMenu = $(this).attr('id');
var displayMenu = '';//yes its blank for a reason
if(whichMenu == 'navi2'){displayMenu = 'menu1';}
if(whichMenu == 'navi3'){displayMenu = 'menu2';}
if(whichMenu == 'navi4'){displayMenu = 'menu3';}
if(whichMenu == 'navi5'){displayMenu = 'menu4';}
if(displayMenu != '')
{
var leftOffset = ($(this).position().left-35);
var topOffset = ($(this).offset().top+$(this).height()+10);
$('#'+displayMenu).css({"display":"block", "position":"absolute", "left":leftOffset+"px", "top":topOffset+"px"});
}
}
var menuitem = $(this).attr('id');
if(menuitem == "navi1"){$(this).css({"background-position":"0 -63px"});}
if(menuitem == "navi2"){$(this).css({"background-position":"-100px -63px"});}
if(menuitem == "navi3"){$(this).css({"background-position":"-230px -63px"});}
if(menuitem == "navi4"){$(this).css({"background-position":"-420px -63px"});}
if(menuitem == "navi5"){$(this).css({"background-position":"-524px -63px"});}
if(menuitem == "navi6"){$(this).css({"background-position":"-638px -63px"});}
if(menuitem == "navi7"){$(this).css({"background-position":"-737px -63px"});}
},
mouseout: function(){
if($('.submenublock').is(":visible") == true){menuTimeout = setInterval(function() {$('.submenublock').fadeOut('slow').css({"display":"none"}); clearInterval(menuTimeout);}, 1500);}
var menuitem = $(this).attr('id');
if(menuitem == "navi1"){$(this).css({"background-position":"0 0"});}
if(menuitem == "navi2"){$(this).css({"background-position":"-100px 0"});}
if(menuitem == "navi3"){$(this).css({"background-position":"-230px 0"});}
if(menuitem == "navi4"){$(this).css({"background-position":"-420px 0"});}
if(menuitem == "navi5"){$(this).css({"background-position":"-524px 0"});}
if(menuitem == "navi6"){$(this).css({"background-position":"-638px 0"});}
if(menuitem == "navi7"){$(this).css({"background-position":"-737px 0"});}
},
click: function(){
window.location = $(this).attr('rel');
}
});
$('.submenublock ul').bind({
mouseover: function(){
clearInterval(menuTimeout);
},
mouseout: function(){
menuTimeout = setInterval(function() {$('.submenublock').fadeOut('slow').css({"display":"none"}); clearInterval(menuTimeout);}, 500);
}
});
```

and here is the site it resides on currently for the sake of seeing the mess in action.
http://kansasoutlawwrestling.com/

**Edit**

Heres a JS fiddle version
http://jsfiddle.net/WveqN/

**Edit 2**
Main reason I am veering away from the CSS option is because there is multiple mouse over/out enter/leave events happening from the main menu item changing to another version via sprite to the menu popping up if there is one to pop up.

Comment: `mouseover` and `mouseout` can be very problematic & quirky in how the mouse fires off those events.  `.hover()` works much better as it combines `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` into one method.  If you don't want to use `hover`, at least use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

Comment: Ok had a look at the site in question, you really need to look at an alternative plugin or css only horizontal hover list http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic2/horizontal04.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@chris,  there is a lot of code to wade through here without any html to back it up so i'm going to give you my generic answer.

1. Why not use a jQuery plugin that already gives you this menu and the
   effect you want?
2. Or try posting this, code and all, on http://jsfiddle.net/ so that
   everyone can play with the code and find a solution?

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/ is a page that lists quite a few free menu plugins as an example.

Comment: +1 and I also recommend a css only menu from http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic2/horizontal04.htm/ much cleaner and easier to debug.